# How to export modules list to Feature?

Tags: 8, features

I want to create Feature with a list of development modules. I want to enable this Feature only in a dev environment.

However I don't see Dependency component in Feature components list.

Do I have any alternatives in D8 for this task?

Can module dependencies only be stored in core.extention.yml only? No alternative way?

But AFAIC this seems that I need to use drush cim/cex commands to keep configuration in current state. I don't like drush cim/cex way at all.

It seems that empty module with dependencies list is the only option